# What is opposite to 'in' condition in Kotlin - '!` mark equivalent to Java

Tags: kotlin

In Java we do use `!` in case we want to say NOT. But what should I use in Kotlin if I follow some range condition.

```
if( item in 5..10)
```

So here I want to say if `item NOT in 5..10` ?? what is the proper construction?

Comment: Note that, in addition to the simpler `!in`, `!` works to negate any condition, just as it does in Java. So `if (!(item in 5..10))` would also work. (You need the extra parens, as `!` has a higher precedence than `in` — just as you need them in Java with e.g. `if (!(item >= 5))`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `!in` operator:

```kotlin
if (item !in 5..10)
```

See documentation for a full list of operators:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#in-operator
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#hard-keywords